# Access Server ipv6 from a ipv4 only network

Tags: ipv4, ipv6

One of my Server is sitting behind a network which is only accessible trough a IPV6 (no double stack IPv4/IPV6 available).

How can I access the server (SSH, HTTP, other protocols) from an network where IPv6 is not available.

I've search for possible technical solutions and there is 4to6 bridge or other such as https://www.sixxs.net  (as example).

Question:

1. Is there an other technical solution which could be similar to sixxs.net (4to6 bridge) which allow all well knowns protocols (ssh, http, ...)
2. Is there an other solution / workaround / service which let me access my ipv6 only server from a ipv4 only network.

Comment: Unfortunately, product and resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: I'm not asking about a product, I'm looking for a technical solution which could be desribed by a so called "service".

Comment: "_Is there an other service similar to sixxs.net_" is asking for a resource recommendation, and that is off-topic here. The recommendations which are off-topic are not limited to products, but to resources, too. We cannot recommend anything like what you are asking. Recommendations lead to opinion-based answer (off-topic) and arguments (mine is better than yours, etc.), and the community has voted to make these off-topic, as have most SE sites.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the dual-stack option is not viable for you, then you will need to use the tunnel option, I believe.

You can try the list on Wikipedia that has several brokers listed, and perhaps you will find a provider that suits you.

[WIKI here](https://web.archive.org/web/20220528205021/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IPv6_tunnel_brokers)

Alternatively you can perhaps setup your own tunnel if you get an intermediary server that runs IPv6 and IPv4 using the instructions listed [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160912004129/https://www.smashnet.de/?p=736)

Hope this helps you on your quest.

Comment: If you need a tunnel that can be used from most IPv4 networks, it pretty much has to be UDP based. That rules out all of those providers who only support 6in4. If you additionally need to be able to do some subnetting you are going to need a prefix which is shorter than /64. And it turns out that not even a single of the providers in that Wikipedia article can satisfy both requirements.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually make use of the [Tor Project](https://www.torproject.org/), it works for me beautifully in a situation where I'm in an IPv4-only network, behind a NAT, and want to connect to an IPv6-only host. The easiest way is to download their Tor Browser, which is just Firefox with some custom settings, and a neat SOCKS proxy program, bundled together. When you open the settings, you can find this:

[image: Connection Settings screen of the Tor Browser]

Here you can see that the browser connects to the SOCKS proxy via `127.0.0.1:9150`. Armed with this knowledge, you can use this proxy to access any place at any port.

Example `ssh` command:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='nc -x 127.0.0.1:9150 %h %p' user@example.net
```

Comment: You *can* use Tor, but it has horrific latency and file transfer speeds. VNC for example is a no-go. Even just typing commands over SSH is painful. It's fine if you want to SFTP yourself a small document you forgot to sync, or to do basic remote maintenance, though.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a way to enable this from the service provider side, but this probably will come with a price tag. Or - to put it another way - opens a path to genereate revenue for the provider by offering IPv4 as an add-on service.

Consider talking to your datacenter provider about services based on [**SIIT-DC**](https://toreanderson.github.io/2016/02/22/ipv6-only-data-centre-rfcs-published.html) as defined in RFCs [7755](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7755), [7756](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7756) and [7757](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7757)

Quoting the author (first link):

> In a nutshell, SIIT-DC works like this: when an IPv4 packet is sent to a service hosted in a data centre (such as a web site), that packet is intercepted by a device called an SIIT-DC Border Relay (BR) as soon as it reaches the data centre. The BR translates the IPv4 packet to IPv6, after which it is forwarded to the IPv6 web server just like any other IPv6 packet. The server’s reply gets routed back to a BR, where it is translated from IPv6 to IPv4, and forwarded through the IPv4 Internet back to the client. Neither the client nor the server need to know that translation between IPv4 and IPv6 is taking place; the IPv4 client thinks it’s talking to a regular IPv4 server, while the IPv6 server thinks it’s talking to a regular IPv6 client.